# IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code in a for loop,

Tags: sql, winforms, c#-4.0

I've researched the other answers here but none of them really fit my case. I've added a table to the database and now I am getting this error. Thing is, it worked on someone else's computer, but in mine, I'm getting the following error. p.s. My connections are fine (in case you wandered):

IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code

```
An exception of type `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
```

Additional information: Cannot find table 0.

The offending code is the initializing of int i = 0 in the for loop

Here is my code

```
 tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["RoleName"].ToString();
            tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
        }
```

Comment: It seems that `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count` is what is causing the exception, rather than an incorrect row count being returned.  Are you sure your connection is working?

Comment: yah its working

Comment: ds.Tables[0] try to access the first table in your dataset, which is not there. Why your DataSet is empty i can't suggest with this informations.

Comment: Set breakpoint on first line of your posted-code. Take the mouse and watch on Tables list. There won't be any Table.